# move fields into the column shelf of Tableau with out having it "split" the values at the top of the column

Tags: dashboard, tableau-api

I've tried my best to synthesize my question in the most simple terms.  Basically, I have a dataset with dimensions for each each supplier. The dimensions include: "Financial Health" (High, Medium, Low) and "Security of Supply" (High, Medium, Low).  I want to build a view that shows the supplier in the rows and has the columns: "Financial Health" and "Security of Supply"- each as it's own column.  The view would contain the actual "value" of the supplier's "Financial Health", and "Security of Supply" as one of Tableau's highlight tables (for example: Supplier 1 might have a low "Financial Health" which would be colored red, and might have a high "Security of Supply" and be colored green, etc.).  The problem is when I move "Financial Health" and "Security of Supply" to the column shelf Tableau splits it into "low", "medium", and "high" columns within both "Financial Health" and "Security of Supply".  In other words these "values" are split at the column-level and do not explicitly show in the view.

Thanks, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put them on the row shelf to the right of supplier.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473320/441979 for an explantion

Comment: I provided the answer to the question, just didn't repeat the explanation behind if. Instead referring him to the explanation from the last time I answered the question.